# Making cURL requests with token, how to persist token

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

I need to get data from a third-party API (peplink). The way I set this up is by using Laravel. First, I make cURL requests to obtain the token. Then, when I receive the token, I pass it as a Bearer token in the CURL-header.

All of this is working, but calls are taking more than 1 second to complete. When I cURL from the terminal I get responses in 200ms. I think I'm on the wrong path because every time I receive data, a new access token is generated.

```
public function login()
{
    $response = Http::asForm()->post('https://api.ic.peplink.com/api/oauth2/token', [
        'client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
    ]);
    $this->token = json_decode($response, true)['access_token'];
}

public function list_devices()
{
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $this->token,
        'Keep-Alive' => 'timeout=5, max=100'
    ])->get('https://api.ic.peplink.com/rest/o/pY0gKf/n/5/d/basic');

    return $response->body();
}
```

The following code is used to get the data.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PeplinkController as PepClient;
...
public function testing() {
    $pepconnection = new PepClient;
    $login = $pepconnection->login();
    $devices = $pepconnection->list_devices();

    return $devices;
}
```

When checking the headers, I also see a JSESSIONID; I think that I need to implement this also?

```
Date: Tue, 06 Jul 2021 12:10:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 657
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Powered-By: JSP/2.3
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=T_zvj29dOxMqY32ionUWzvM_QmMTr6AjrXyr0zq6.co6-1; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-API-TOKEN, Cache-Control
Server: IC2
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, PUT, DELETE, GET, OPTIONS
```

Comment: _“im thinking that i need to implement the use of this also?”_ - I am thinking that you should probably consult the API documentation, instead of playing a guessing game.

Comment: _“because everytime i receive data, a new access token is generated”_ - so store the one you got the first time around then, and use it in your subsequent requests …?

Comment: The api documentation doesnt give me any good direction. Im complete newbie in this. About storing the token, how can I save a token serverside? Im not passing anything to the my vuejs application.

Comment: Does not seem to be a user-specific token, so storing it into the user session probably doesn’t make much sense. Put it into the database, or write it into a file (not accessible from the outside) then. We don’t currently know whether that token is valid forever, or might be time restricted. Some APIs offer endpoints to _check_ token validity, but that is probably not something to do on each request either here, will likely slow the thing down pretty much the same way. Alternative would be to try and make your actual API request first, and if that fails due to an expired token, get a new one.